# How to include module level CSS in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm having angular project consist of Frontend and admin. I want to scale my project in such a way that I use different CSS for both admin and frontend.

Structure of my project is as follows:

```
--app
   --admin // Admin Module
     --admin.module.ts
     --admin.component.ts
     --admin-routing.module.ts
     --admin.component.css
     --admin.component.html

  --web // Frontend Module
     --web.module.ts
     --web.component.ts
     --web-routing.module.ts
     --web.component.css
     --web.component.html 

--app.module.ts
--app.component.ts
--app-routing.module.ts
--app.component.css
--app.component.html
```

I've defined my CSS for web(Frontend) in **.angular-cli.json** file.

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

How can I load different CSS file for admin and the web? 
Also is there any better approach to include multiple modules in same project?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127523/how-can-i-load-a-custom-css-file-both-in-adminpanel-and-frontend

Answer (score 2):

You can define the global css properties that are common for both admin and remaining users in the `"styles.css"` file and admin specific & remaining user specific css properties could be defined in `admin.component.css` and `web.component.css` respectively;Hope this helps

Comment: I tried importing css on module level - `@import './assets/styles.css';
`, still no results are reflected? What can be the reason

Comment: where are you trying to do this import ?? You dont have to import any module level imports ..thats imported by default

Comment: Consider I'm writing following css in `web.component.css` - `body { 
    font-family: Montserrat,Montserrat-Light,Montserrat-Regular,Montserrat-Bold,Montserrat-Black,sans-serif !important;
    padding-top: 100px; 
}` , No results is refected at web level

Comment: please post update your code with web component and web component html and do you have any error on the console ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a main component for each module, you just have to attach the .css file to your component in the @Component() decorator.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './admin.component.html'
    styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
```

---

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './web.component.html'
    styleUrls: ['./web.component.css']
})
```